# Reading grib2 data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Does anyone have any experience reading grib2 data? Looking to add functionality to one of my weather apps but can't seem to find a whole lot on grib2, or how one would get it into a readable form.

Comment: I don't, but it looks like [there's an API for it](http://www.ecmwf.int/products/data/software/grib_api.html).

Comment: Looks promising, but I wouldn't even know how to start integrating this with an existing iOS app.. Don't have much experience with C.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) that you can use to extract data from grib2 files. I use it from the command line to extract time series at a chosen lat/lon location, but it can do other kinds of slicing & dicing.